# How to solve "undefined symbols for architecture x86_64" and "linker command failed with exit code 1" in xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, macos

I am trying to build a project in xcode and I get the following errors:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_Zoom", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in ZoomConnectedNetworking.o
      objc-class-ref in ZoomViewController.o
      objc-class-ref in RNAppBridge-843d3738eaf9ad6c9a88b86d7afb070208b29a596e7ec9fd5f0c00a394da72ff.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_ZoomCancelButtonCustomization", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in ZoomConnectedConfig.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_ZoomCustomization", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in ZoomConnectedConfig.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_ZoomFeedbackCustomization", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in ZoomConnectedConfig.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_ZoomFrameCustomization", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in ZoomConnectedConfig.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_ZoomInstructionsImages", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in ZoomConnectedConfig.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_ZoomOvalCustomization", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in ZoomConnectedConfig.o
  "_construct_single_private_key", referenced from:
      static pingpongRN.GothamClient.getSinglePrivateKey(x1: Swift.String, x2: Swift.String) -> Swift.String? in GothamClient.o
  "_decrypt_party_one_master_key", referenced from:
      static pingpongRN.GothamClient.decryptPartyOneMasterKey(client_share: pingpongRN.MasterKey2, encrypted_server_share: Swift.String, private_key: Swift.String) -> Swift.String? in GothamClient.o
  "_get_child_mk1", referenced from:
      static pingpongRN.GothamClient.getChildServerShare(server_share_str: Swift.String, x_pos: Swift.String, y_pos: Swift.String) -> Swift.String? in GothamClient.o
  "_get_child_mk2", referenced from:
      static pingpongRN.GothamClient.getChildClientShare(client_share_str: Swift.String, x_pos: Swift.String, y_pos: Swift.String) -> pingpongRN.MasterKey2? in GothamClient.o
  "_get_client_master_key", referenced from:
      static pingpongRN.GothamClient.generate_master_key2(gothamEndpoint: Swift.String) -> (pingpongRN.MasterKey1?, pingpongRN.MasterKey2?) in GothamClient.o
  "_sign_message", referenced from:
      static pingpongRN.GothamClient.sign(gothamEndpoint: Swift.String, message_hex: Swift.String, x_pos: Swift.String, y_pos: Swift.String, master_key_2: pingpongRN.MasterKey2, master_key1_id: Swift.String) -> pingpongRN.Signature? in GothamClient.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I tried cleaning and I have read about looking at the linking but it seems like all of the libraries and frameworks I need are in place.

Any reason why this is happening?

Answer (score 1):

There several possible reasons:

1. You linked the library that has no architectures for Simulator ( seems that you're building for simulator ) - to check that you can simply thought terminal:

```
lipo -info LIBRARY_OR_FRAMEWORK_FILE (it will show you all compatible architectures)
```

2. You completely not linking library:
   To check that just more to "Build Phase" tab and look at "Link Binary with Libraries" phase

Comment: ok so 2 seems fine. when running 1 i get the following: fatal error: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/lipo: can't open input file: LIBRARY_OR_FRAMEWORK_FILE (No such file or directory). any ideas?

Comment: coworker gets the same error but everything works from his side so it cant be it